# How to solve table locking on H2 using Spring Boot and JPA?

Tags: spring, jpa, h2, spring-boot

I seem to have struck an issue and have no real clue on how to solve.

My current app is based on Spring Boot with JPA and the following code gets a lock when run for the second execution.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    repository.save(new RawData("test"));
    repository.save(new RawData("test"));

    // hangs when the method index() is run 2 sequentially 
    RawData rawData = rawDataRepository.findOne(1L);
    System.out.println(rawData);

    return "#: " + repository.count();
}
```

When run the first time all seems ok, but executing the same code 2 times gives me a lock on:

```
    RawData rawData = rawDataRepository.findOne(1L);
```

Also trying to connect to the DB gives me a lock timeout when the methods hangs or waits for a timeout.

Calling the same code in Spring Service results in the same behaviour.

```
@Component
public class SyncService {

    @Autowired
    RawDataRepository rawDataRepository;

    void syncWithRemote() {
        // hang on this line...
        RawData rawData = rawDataRepository.findOne(1L);
        System.out.println(rawData);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you calling repository methods from the controller? Start by adding a service interface and see the results.

Comment: I original did that and got the same behaviour. This is just mere test code to explain the problem. I will update the code with the service code also

Answer (score 0):

You should use two techniques:

1. Use optimistic locking by using `@Version` field in your entities
2. Add transactions support by annotating your methods by `@Transactional` annotation. Normally you also have to annotate Configuration class by `@EnableTransactionManagement` but Spring Boot makes it for you

That should solve your problems